# Numerical solutions of a multivariable equation

Tags: equation-solving, version-11.1

I have been desperately trying to find a way to get this equation solved with Mathematica (I am using version 11.1 if that matters):

$$
a\sqrt7 + b\sqrt{11} = (\sqrt7 + \sqrt{11})^{13},
$$

assuming that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

This is a really easy equation to solve and it admits the solution $a=2274430976$ and $b=1814368256$.

So naturally I thought Mathematica would find the result:

```
Solve[{(Sqrt[7] + Sqrt[11])^(13) == a Sqrt[7] + b Sqrt[11] && a > 0 && b > 0}, {a, b}, Integers]
```

But instead, I get a warning message:

```
Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.
```

And then the "solution" is this weird output:

```
{{b -> ConditionalExpression[(2274430976 Sqrt[7] + 1814368256 Sqrt[11] - Sqrt[7] a)/Sqrt[11], (a | (2274430976 Sqrt[7] + 1814368256 Sqrt[11] - Sqrt[7] a)/Sqrt[11]) \[Element] Integers && 1 <= a <= 4548861952]}}
```

So I thought I had to extract the values somehow from the solution, and I tried:

```
sol=Solve[...]
a./sol
```

Which yielded:

```
{a}
```

No help there. Then I tried using `Normal[%]` and `First[%]` and various combinations thereof, but I got even weirder output.

How can I find the correct numerical solutions for $a$ and $b$? All the help I find online ends up in weird warnings. Maybe my Mathematica is too old, and has a different syntax? Can someone help?

---

EDIT: I'm using version **11.1**

Comment: Expand the RHS: `(List @@ ((Sqrt[7] + Sqrt[11])^13 // Expand)) /. _Power :> 1` evaluates to `{2274430976, 1814368256}`

Comment: Could extract coefficients of each square root, like so. `In[241]:= Solve[
 CoefficientList[(Sqrt[7] + Sqrt[11])^(13) - (a*Sqrt[7] + 
      b*Sqrt[11]), {Sqrt[7], Sqrt[11]}] == 0]

Out[241]= {{a -> 2274430976, b -> 1814368256}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expansion yields the result (as expressed by others)

```
expr = (Sqrt[7] + Sqrt[11])^13 // Expand
Sequence @@ Cases[expr, Times[a_, #] :> a] & /@ {Sqrt[7], Sqrt[11]}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. This is the only solution that I can reproduce on Mathematica 11.1 so I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Reduce` instead of `Solve`

```
Reduce[{(Sqrt[7] + Sqrt[11])^(13) == a Sqrt[7] + b Sqrt[11] && a > 0 &&    b > 0}, {a, b}, Integers]

(*a == 2274430976 && b == 1814368256*)
```

Also

```
FindInstance[(Sqrt[7] + Sqrt[11])^(13) == a Sqrt[7] + b Sqrt[11], {a,b}, Integers]
```

Gives the same output.

And also

```
NSolve[{(Sqrt[7] + Sqrt[11])^(13) == a Sqrt[7] + b Sqrt[11] && a > 0 && b > 0}, {a, b}, Integers]
```

Comment: For Reduce, I get this/ $$(a | b) \[Element] Integers && 
 b == 4096/11 (4872571 + 555281 Sqrt[77]) - Sqrt[7/11] a$$, and for FindInstance I get "FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist."

Comment: @Klangen that is weird... I have tried mine and yours code on version 11.3 and it also works. Try restarting Mathematica. If it still doesn't work it might be a version specific problem

Comment: Is it possible that in version 11.3 they switched the behaviour of Solve, from symbolic/conditional to numerical?

Comment: I don't know... but you can also try `NSolve` this is purely numerical @Klangen

Comment: NSolve yields the same warning and ConditionalExpression as Solve

Comment: @Klangen I am afraid this is a version-specific issue: probably the `Solve` family was improved at some point between your version 11.1 and version 11.2 or 11.3

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica v12.2 solves without problems:

```
Solve[{(Sqrt[7] + Sqrt[11])^(13) == a Sqrt[7] + b Sqrt[11] , a > 0,b > 0}, {a, b}, Integers]
(*{{a -> 2274430976, b -> 1814368256}}*)

Solve[{(Sqrt[7] + Sqrt[11])^(13) == a Sqrt[7] + b Sqrt[11] }, {a,b},PositiveIntegers]
(*{{a -> 2274430976, b -> 1814368256}}*)
```

Comment: So then it's because I'm using Mathematica 11.1? Is that the issue? I don't want to have to spend another 400 USD on a newer version every two years...

Comment: In fact it also works in version 13.0 for Linux. Maybe the OP has defined something previously and now this is giving problems...